# Maven versions plugin -- use latest, preferring snapshots

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, versions-maven-plugin

I'm not really clear on [use-latest-snapshots](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-snapshots-mojo.html) and [use-next-snapshots](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-next-snapshots-mojo.html). Basically, I want to update a set of dependencies (not every one) to the latest. If a snapshot is available, I want to force using that instead of the release version. For example...

- Referenced version: **1.3.5** Available versions: 1.3.6, 1.3.6-SNAPSHOT -> **1.3.6-SNAPSHOT**
- Referenced version: **1.3.5-SNAPSHOT** Available versions: 1.3.6 (only) -> **1.3.6**
- Referenced version: **1.3.6** Available versions: 1.3.6, 1.3.6-SNAPSHOT -> **1.3.6-SNAPSHOT**

I don't want to add timestamps to any snapshot versions. Is tehre any way to achieve this with maven versions plugin?

Comment: What if the latest snapshot is _before_ the latest version? Latest snapshot is 1.0-SNAPSHOT but latest version is 1.3?

Comment: @Tunaki - use the non-snapshot one. that's one of the examples.